# how to use customized toolbar in multiple viewcontroller without repeating the code and copying the elements (swift)?

Tags: ios, swift, iphone, toolbar, viewcontroller

how to use customized toolbar in multiple viewcontroller without repeating the code and copying the elements (swift)?

trying to create XIB with the toolbar

"i'm asking if I have already customized the toolbar and i need to use it in multi-able viewcontrollers without repeating the what i have already do  "

Answer (score 2):

**From Storyboard**

- Go to StoryBoard
- Select your initial ViewController
- On the top click Editor>Embed In>Navigation Controller
- Select the navigation controller go to Attributes Inspector>Bottom Bar and choose your desired toolbar.

Now everytime you create a new ViewController and perform a segue the toolbar will appear automatically.

**Programmatically**

In the viewDidLoad() of your rootViewController

```
let toolBar = UINib(nibName: "ToolBar", bundle: nil).instantiateWithOwner(nil, 
options: nil).first as! YourToolBarClass
self.navigationController!.view.addSubview(toolBar)
self.navigationController!.toolbarItems = toolBar.items
```

To all ViewControllers:

```
self.toolbarItems = self.navigationController!.toolbarItems
```

Comment: i'm asking if I have already customized the toolbar and i need to use it in multi-able viewcontrollers without repeating the what i have already do

Comment: See the second approach.

Comment: could you please tell me how to create toolbar in separated xib file and separated class and use it in multiable view controller ?

Comment: I think the best for you is to see some tutorials on youtube. Basically you should design your xib then declare all the element in your xib's class and then do the 2nd approach.

Comment: with "self.navigationController!.view.addSubview(toolBar)
self.navigationController!.toolbarItems = toolBar.items"
??? as well